# Error when try to connect to infura using HDWallet

Tags: truffle, rinkeby, infura, rpc

I would like to debug a transaction using truffle and infura.

```
truffle debug --network=infurarinkeby 0x7...
```

truffle-config.js:

```
    infurarinkeby: {
        provider: function() {
            return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/<my api key>")
        },
        network_id: 4,
        gas: 6e6,
        gasPrice: 5e10,
        from: "0xc491c11f6c2e031e99d7c93300baced83019041d"
    },
```

Error:

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

Comment: Just a guess, but is Truffle case sensitive here? Try `--network=infuraRinkeby ...`?

Comment: I changed it. If you provide a wrong network name you will get a different error message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the debug API isn't supported from infura:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/890

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using your Infura Project ID and not the Project Secret.